# fetching content inside <p> tags in wordpress

Tags: php, dom, curl, xampp

I am trying to fetch contents inside `<p>` tags. I read that for HTML parsing in PHP one should opt for DOM parser. I am trying to use `str_get_html` and `file_get_html` but i am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_get_html()

I am working on xampp (version = 1.7.7). Do I need to modify **php.ini** file ? I have already said `allow_url_fopen = On` and I am able to user `curl` functions also to get website content.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to use the str_get_html() function, you will need to first download a module which defines this function and include it at the top of your php script.

Heres the [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/1.5/simplehtmldom_1_5.zip/download) to download

Copy the simple_html_dom.php file to the folder where your script is and add the following line of code to the top of YOUR php script..

```
include('simple_html_dom');
```